# Disable intel hd graphic card for asus n55sf

Tags: graphics-card, bios

I have an Asus N55SF, and i have a problem with the intel graphic, the screen always gets black (with some liltle white dots on the left side of the screen), and when i gently hit the pc sometimes the screen gets back to normal.
Now when i open a game or anything that uses the nVidia graphic cards, this problem never happens,  or when i plug the laptop to an external monitor, so how can i turn off or disable this intel graphic.
I tried to disable it from the "Device Manager", i get a warning, and when i press ok the screen goes black and i cant do anything, also tried to go to BIOS, but i couldnt find any option related to the graphic card, here s what i have in BIOS:
Under advanced:
[image]
and under Intel(R) AT Configuration:
[image]

Comment: As I came to find recently.  The dedicated GPU you have required the integrated GPU to work.  Disabling the integrated GPU isn't going to solve your problems the little white dots will not disappear, without the integrated GPU, you wouldn't get any display.

Comment: so the only option is to fix the intel graphic card? and one more question, the intel graphic card is INSIDE the cpu? or it is on its own, meaning do i have to buy a new intel graphic card or a new cpu?

Comment: You have a laptop so it means replacing the entire motherboard which in the process will replace your CPU and the integrated GPU.

Comment: no no i dont want to replace the whole motherboard, i want to replace just the intel graphic card ... or that is impossible?

Comment: You can't just replace the motherboard since its integrated into your CPU which is likely soldered on to the motherboard.  You provided no information about which processor you have and I have learn ASUS does a horrible job with model specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing  <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>. Sounds bizarre but it seems to be working.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your post needs to be expanded. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes specific instructions (not just links to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to add detail explaining your solution.